# SharePoint sign out not working in Google Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, forms-authentication, chrome

We have an Extranet SharePoint environment published in Internet for our clients. The issue is that if the user is using the Chrome browser and even if they select "Sign Out" or just close the browser, their session remains still open and the next person to visit that site is logged in with the previous user's credentials. Many of our users will be logging onto this SharePoint site from public computers so this is a huge security risk. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Sign in as Different User** option. If you are creating custom sign out button then you can bind url as `_/layouts/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true`

Note : This might approach may ask for credentials again but your user would be definitely logged out from the extranet site

Reference : [Sign in as different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139527/sign-in-as-different-user-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the following which can be found within Chrome Settings under the “On Startup” heading:

“**Continue where I left off**” is probably selected.

If you switch it to “Open the new tab page” that will likely solve your issue.

Alternatively, you could take the following steps as recommended on the [Google help page describing this setting](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en):

Your cookies and data are saved, so any websites you were logged into before (like Gmail, for example) will open again. If you don't want to be automatically signed in to these pages, follow the steps below:

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More->**Settings**.
3. At the bottom, click **Advanced**.
4. Under "Privacy and security," click **Content settings**.
5. Click **Cookies**.
6. Turn on **Keep local data only until you quit your browser**.